# Converts data in a HashMap to a custom object

Tags: java, stream

I have a `HashMap` and I want to convert data in it to a `Response` object, but I do not find it clean and optimized. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
class Converter{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
      map.put("111", 80) // first 
      map.put("1A9|ppp", 190) // second
      map.put("98U|6765", 900) // third
      map.put("999|aa|local", 95) // fourth

      List<Response> responses = new ArrayList<>();
      for(String key : map.keySet()){
        Response response = new Response();
        String[] str  = key.split("\\|");
        response.id = str[0] //id is always present in key i.e 111, 1A9, 98U,999
        if(str.length == 2) {
             if(str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");){ // check if is numeric
                  response.code = str[1]; // 6765
             }
             else{
                  response.city = str[1]; //ppp
             }
        }
         if(str.length == 3){
                  response.client = str[1]; //aa
                  response.type = str[2];   // local
         } 
        response.qty = map.get[key];
        responses.add(response);
      }
   }
}


class Response{

String id;
String city;
Long code;
String client;
String type;
Long qty;
// getters and setters

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a String to represent the response? Why not have a `HashMap<Response, Long>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dustytrash already mentioned in a comment, it would be much more sensible to simply use the `Response` object as the map key and be done.

If this is not possible due to unknown external constraints, move the translation to and from `String` into the `Response` object.

```
class Response {
    public static Response fromString(String s) {
        // ... do the parsing here
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // generate "98U|6765" or whatever
        // debatable: maybe don't use the overridden toString for the technical representation
    }
}
```

This encapsulates the nitty-gritty details of conversion in the class itself.

The converson then boils down to

```
map.keySet().stream()
    .map(Response::fromString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you. But i also wanted to know if there a way to improve parsing

Comment: And how to set the qty ?